# MVC C# - Export PdfPTable to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, document, export-to-excel

I am working on downloading a `PDF document`. I have used `PdfPTable` to create a table. Below is my shortened code.

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);                
var output = new MemoryStream();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

document.Open();

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.WidthPercentage = 80;

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description", fntTableFontBold));
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.AddCell(cell);

......
document.Add(table);
document.Close();

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.pdf", "Journal"));
Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
```

All is working fine. Above code straight away downloads the PDF in browser.

Now i want to add Download to Excel functionality, User should be able to Download document in Excel format.

How to convert this above code to export as `.xls`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

[Open Xml SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)

to achieve this as this allows to create the whole thing in memory as well.
Another options are:

1. Creating excel by starting Excel Interop process (Office install required)
2. Connecting to excel file as to the db using JET or ACE engine (depends if you need to support x86 or x64 architecure)

Than of course you change response object accordingly to inform browser that you are sending excel.